# Using Otto, method only subscribes if I call it directly elsewhere

Tags: java, android, proguard, otto

I have an issue where one of my *subscribed* methods does not get called upon a post of the correct event type unless that *subscribed* method is used (called) elsewhere.

Here is some relevant information about the code:

- A method of one of my classes is annotated with @Subscribe.
- By stepping through the code with the debugger, I find that under my specific circumstance, the class has no methods annotated with @Subscribe.
- Unless I call the method directly at some point in time (doesn't matter when, or even if it actually gets called at runtime) elsewhere, my *post* does not work.
- The IDE (Android Studio) notifies me that the "method is never used"

I can certainly call the method in a block of code that I am confident will never fire, but this is obviously terrible practice, and defeats the purpose of this post/subscribe paradigm.

Or I can make the method static, but I'd rather not because I use member variables inside of it.

Any solutions to why this is occuring even though Otto's example uses a similar pattern

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out it was a ProGuard issue. Fixed it by adding the following lines:

```
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @com.squareup.otto.Subscribe public *;
    @com.squareup.otto.Produce public *;
}
```

Comment: Which file did you add this to?

Comment: This link should help you: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html
Pretty much, if you don't have a custom proguard file already, you can specify the location of one in your build.gradle file and add these lines to it